# How to draw text with different font formatting to a canvas in delphi at once?

Tags: delphi

I've been using `DrawText` for all my "text in rectangle" output needs, however I'm failing to see a way to draw a string, for example, with every other word bold or of different color, or, even worse, different backgrounds for said randomly selected words. There probably is no single procedure that can do this as far as I can see, I might be wrong, that's the main point of this question. Can someone point at procedures that could be of interest to someone trying to achieve such effects? Additionally, if I am correct and there is no simple way of doing this, what would be the recommended path to take? Drawing every word separately and then trying to glue all of that together seems like a nightmare when you start thinking of issues that can arise from that, top of my head: proper text alignment on a single horizontal line when you have varying fonts or sizes...

I've got delphi xe3; if someone can improve the phrasing of my question and/or text, please do so.

Comment: You absolutely can not do it **at once**. You could however delegate this job to smth like metafile and then blit the rendering result to you canvas achieving apparent *at once* effect. WinGDI canvas only recognizes a very basic formatting codes like line-feeds or tabs.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You get some help from the VCL, since the `TCanvas.TextOut` method increases the `x` coordinate of the pen pos by the width of the output string:

```
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Canvas.MoveTo(20, 100);

  Canvas.Font.Name := 'Segoe UI';
  Canvas.Font.Color := clMaroon;
  Canvas.Font.Style := [];
  Canvas.Font.Height := 64;
  Canvas.TextOut(Canvas.PenPos.X, Canvas.PenPos.Y, 'This ');

  Canvas.Font.Color := clNavy;
  Canvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];
  Canvas.Font.Height := 64;
  Canvas.TextOut(Canvas.PenPos.X, Canvas.PenPos.Y, 'is ');

  Canvas.Font.Name := 'Bookman Old Style';
  Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
  Canvas.Font.Style := [fsItalic];
  Canvas.Font.Height := 64;
  Canvas.TextOut(Canvas.PenPos.X, Canvas.PenPos.Y, 'a ');

  Canvas.Font.Name := 'Courier New';
  Canvas.Font.Color := clSilver;
  Canvas.Font.Style := [];
  Canvas.Font.Height := 64;
  Canvas.TextOut(Canvas.PenPos.X, Canvas.PenPos.Y, 'test!');
end;
```

[image: Screenshot]

Anyhow, if you need more advanced text output routines, why not have a look at [DirectWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368038(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: i like DrawText at least for it's word wrap abilities, with textout i'd need to handle that, which doesnt make the situation any easier, loose the luxury of word wrapping and other options for better looking text... and also, specifying height scales the size of the font? or just picks an appropriate font size for that height?

Comment: @Raith: The latter. Anyhow, if you need more advanced text output routines, why not have a look at [DirectWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368038(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: DirectWrite (or anything windows programming for that matter) is not something I am familiar with. Actually, you put it correctly: "advanced text output routines", if DirectWrite does that, it might be exactly what i am looking for, thank you. I need to investigate. I will inform if this suffices as an answer.

Comment: DirectWrite is amazing and exactly what I needed, I had to study some C++ examples to get it working  though (and I don't know C++, the syntax is... just confusing). If you are to edit your answer or provide a new one I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using Richedit with it's rather rich formatting abilities? If you need to draw text on canvas, not in window, then EM_FORMATRANGE message allows to copy graphical representation of formatted text.

Comment: rich (adj.) <> reach (v.; n.)

Comment: this is something i did not know, interesting idea, i need to look into it

Comment: an example can be found here http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/de/showcode.php?id=2146