# How to draw on a canvas a multi-line text with some words in bold/colored?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

How to draw on a canvas, inside a defined Rect, a **MULTILINE** text with some words in bold/colored? on firemonkey ...

this is not the same question as [How to draw text with different font formatting to a canvas in delphi at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061328/how-to-draw-text-with-different-font-formatting-to-a-canvas-in-delphi-at-once) because me i want to draw a multiline text on firemonkey ! a text that break to fit inside a Rect. something like canvas.FillText but with a way to set some word in bold/colored

Comment: It should be very straight-forward based on that other answer. The only difference is once you've reached the end of one line, increment the Y by the height of the text. Each time you draw, use `Canvas.TextHeight` and compare it to the maximum height. If it's larger than the last, then update it. By the time you draw the next line, you'll know how far down to draw.

Comment: Also, the second answer on that other question would work perfectly for multi-line text. In addition, that first answer also mentions how WinAPI provides yet another alternative, also supporting multi-line. With all this available in that other question, I too will vote to close as duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw text with different font formatting to a canvas in delphi at once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061328/how-to-draw-text-with-different-font-formatting-to-a-canvas-in-delphi-at-once)

Comment: @jerry, how you know that you have reach the end of the line ? say i have the line "blabla bliblibli bloblo" + (bold)"blebleble" + "blublublu blyblybly" ... 
how to break it?

Comment: @ken: my question is not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061328/how-to-draw-text-with-different-font-formatting-to-a-canvas-in-delphi-at-once, their is even not a single note about multiline in this question ! i know how to put word in bold or in colored, i m mostly interested how to BREAK a text. this is clearly say in my question ...

Comment: It was **not** in the first version that you deleted. I know - I was the one who closed it. As I said, you **really** need to improve the quality of your posts here. You're not new any more, and you know how the site works and what is expected of you by now.

Comment: it's was, it's exactly the same text instead that in this question i put in bold the word "multiline" and add firemonkey (because the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061328/how-to-draw-text-with-different-font-formatting-to-a-canvas-in-delphi-at-once is not for firemonkey, their is not textout on firemonkey)

Comment: Will you just stop arguing and listen to what people are telling you? I did not close **this question** as a duplicate of the other one. Why are you pestering me about it now? Stop posting crap to my inbox. Stop arguing when I"m not arguing with you. And your other post did not include Firemonkey in either the body or tags.

Comment: Two of those solutions in the other question directly relate to word breaks. Did you read the answers in their entirety? Did you look at the WinAPI documentation, as linked in the other question? In case you didn't, here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368038(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @JerryDodge thanks first ! No i can't use the winapi, because i m on firemonkey, their is even no canvas.textout on Firemonkey ... also i don't see anything corresponding to word break in this question... it's not so easy to split a sentence in several lines ...

Comment: @KenWhite not understand what you mean by arguing ? i didn't start to say you anything, it's you that first close my question and after say "next time, put in effort" ... i just answer you gently that you too next time read carefully the question, or ask before to close it ...

Comment: No, I read the question carefully. It did **not** mention Firemonkey, and it was a very poor quality post that read just like the duplicate I used to close it. As I said, **try harder** when you post a question here, and make it **very clear** what you're asking, and provide the details, and you won't have problems with accidental closure. **You're not new here any more** - it's time to learn to write **clear, specific questions** that make it **very clear** what you're asking and provide the needed details (such as that it's about FMX and not VCL).

Comment: Well now that I know you're using Firemonkey, I don't know what to say. It's an entirely different question now.

Comment: The question is rather weak. What is the single specific thing you want help with. Re write the question to bring that specific issue into sharp relief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so finally they was no easy way to achieve this. normally the most easy way (and an acceptable answer) will be to use **TTextLayout**. TTextlayout is quite performant and support formatting. problem is that it's lack of some other think, like for exemple colored emoticons on android

so i end up by writing my own function that **break** the text. this function is too big to be post here but you can saw it https://svn.code.sf.net/p/alcinoe/code/ unit alFmxCommon

```
function  ALDrawMultiLineText(const aText: String; // support only theses EXACT html tag :
                                                   //   <b>...</b>
                                                   //   <i>...</i>
                                                   //   <font color="#xxxxxx">...</font>
                                                   //   <span id="xxx">...</span>
                                                   // other < > must be encoded with &lt; and &gt;
                              var aRect: TRectF; // in => the constraint boundaries in real pixel. out => the calculated rect that contain the html in real pixel
                              var aTextBreaked: boolean; // true is the text was "breaked" in several lines
                              var aAscent: single; // out => the Ascent of the last element (in real pixel)
                              var aDescent: Single; // out => the Descent of the last element (in real pixel)
                              var aFirstPos: TpointF; // out => the point of the start of the text
                              var aLastPos: TpointF; // out => the point of the end of the text
                              var aElements: TalTextElements; // out => the list of rect describing all span elements
                              var aEllipsisRect: TRectF; // out => the rect of the Ellipsis (if present)
                              const aOptions: TALDrawMultiLineTextOptions): {$IFDEF _USE_TEXTURE}TTexture{$ELSE}Tbitmap{$ENDIF};
```

it's absolutely not trivial to break the text in several line and add also formatting to this text and this for all plateform